# How to write a Bash Script for Pushgateway and prometheus

Tags: bash, prometheus-pushgateway

I am trying to use a bash script for Pushgateway and Prometheus, but can't get it working.
I have Pushgateway on my raspberry and Prometheus on another raspberry. All work correctly and I test a simple bash script, this script works correctly.
My simple script (test.sh):

```
echo "metric 99" | curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/some_job
```

Now I want to write a more complex script. This script must push to prometheus the metric from CPU usage (the same as the "$ps aux" command or same as "$ top" command). But this script doesn't work and I don't know what to do to modify it..
My more complex script :

```
#!/bin/bash
z="ps aux"

while read -r $z
do
    var=$var$(awk '{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\"}", $3$z}');
done <<< "$z"
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: text/plain" --data "$var" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

If anyone could help me. Thanks a lot.

I also try this code :

```
#!/bin/bash
z="ps aux"

while read -r "ps aux"
do
    var=$var$(awk '{print "cpu_usage{process=\""$11"\", pid=\""$2"\"}", $3$z}');
done <<< "$z"
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: text/plain" --data "$var" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

But I am not sure about the syntax. What's wrong ?

I try the code :

```
load=$(ps aux | awk '{ print "cpu_usage{ process=\"" $11 "\",pid=\"" $2 "\"}," $3 }')
curl -X POST -H --data "$load" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

But it doesn't work. The first line is ok, but when i run this code, I find an error message to the curl command:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

========== **The solution to my problem is :**    ==========

```
ps aux | awk '$3>0 {print "cpu_usage"$2" "$3""}' | curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

This command could transfer to the pushgateway all process data with % CPU > 0. In this line, $3 = %CPU, $2 = PID. Be carefull with special caracters. If the result command is an error message, maybe it is because there is special caracter...

Comment: tip: `var=$var...` just `var+=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/!\ **The solution to my problem is :**     /!\

```
ps aux | awk '$3>0 {print "cpu_usage"$2" "$3""}' | curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

This command could transfer to the pushgateway all process data with % CPU > 0. In this line, $3 = %CPU, $2 = PID. Be carefull with special caracters. If the result command is an error message, maybe it is because there is special caracter...

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is too complex, divide it into smaller, more manageable pieces and see what they do. Start by analysing  output from the awk part.

AWK can be a bit of a handful.

Try a simpler approach:

```sh
ps aux | tr -s ' ' ',' | cut -d, -f2,11 |
while read pid process; do
    req="cpu_usage{process=$process,pid=$pid}"
    echo "Sending CURL Request with this data: $req"
    curl -X POST -H "Content-type: text/plain" --data "$req" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
 done
```

You may want to review the brackets. I have no means of testing this.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I am doing, but I spend to must time and I am not sure about bash script syntax. That's why I need some help.

Comment: Here's a simpler approach which will help you learn the syntax.    ps aux | tr -s ' ' ',' | cut -d, -f2,11 | while read pid process; do req="cpu_usage{process=$process,pid=$pid}"; echo $req; done

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about several details of basic Bash syntax.

```sh
command <<<"string"
```

simply passes the literal `string` as standard input to `command`. The syntax you seem to be looking for is the process substitution

```sh
command < <(other)
```

which runs `other` and passes its output as input to `command`. But this too is an overcomplication; you probably want a simpler straight pipeline.

```sh
load=$(ps aux | awk '{ print "cpu_usage{ process=\"" $11 "\",pid=\"" $2 "\"}," $3 }')
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: text/plain" --data "$load" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine
```

where I had to resort to some wild speculation around what you hoped the Awk script should do.

Also, the argument to `read` is the name of a variable, so `read z`, not `read $z` (and usually use `read -r` unless you specifically require the odd legacy behavior of `read` with backslashes in its input).

Finally, you basically never want to store a command in a variable; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Going forward, probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: Thanks all for helping me. I try the code : 'load=$(ps aux | awk '{ print "cpu_usage{ process=\"" $11 "\",pid=\"" $2 "\"}," $3 }')
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: text/plain" --data "$load" http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/top/instance/machine'  but it doesn't work correctly. I find a error message : "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL. I don't know why...

Comment: The error message suggests something with the URL rather than with the data in `"$load"`. Without knowledge of what exactly your `ps` output looks like or how the POST data should look, there are several free variables here; it would help if you could update your question to provide more details around these matters. As you can tell here, code in comments doesn't work very well at all.

Comment: Does `echo "$load"` look like what you expect?

Comment: Yes when I run echo "$load" the response is what I want.

Comment: The error message in your screenshot looks like it's using `"$load"` as the URL. I notice that your first, working attempt uses a cuite different syntax for passing in the data.

Comment: I try to change the <"$load"> position into the curl ligne. I think the result could be better, because I don't have curl error message BUT now I have this kind of message : "invalid metric name" or "unexpected end of label value" or " expected float as value, got", so I understand the data to transfert is not in the correct form..

Comment: Without knowlede about what the server on `localhost` expects or does, we can't help with that part. Perhaps (accept this answer and) ask a new question about that with enough details.

Comment: Based on a quick read of https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/blob/master/README.md it looks like you should have a space instead of a comma before `$3`. But this probably also depends on other things; I've never heard of this service.

Comment: Yes I will ask a new question. Thanks for all !